# Append JSON objects to same object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vuejs2

I get form elements from VueJS function call in a HTML form. I create a JSON like:

```
var elements = event.target.elements;
var form_elements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = {};
    element[elements[i].getAttribute('name')] = elements[i].value;
    form_elements.push(element);
}
form_elements = JSON.stringify(form_elements);
```

I get the JSON as follows:

`var form_elements = [{'name':'John'},{'age':'20'},{'gender':'Male'},];`

I want to convert this into:

`var form_elements = {'name':'John','age':'20','gender':'Male'};`

for ajax call. How to do this?

Comment: I added answer with minimal code, hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to combine the elements to a single object:

```
var elements = event.target.elements;

var form_elements = elements.reduce(function(r, el) {
  r[el.getAttribute('name')] = el.value;

  return r;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 2):

a temporary variable in `for` block is useless in your case, the final code maybe looks like this:

```
var elements = event.target.elements;
var form_elements = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    form_elements[elements[i].getAttribute('name')] = elements[i].value;
}
```

and the `form_elements` is what you need finally, try to `JSON.stringify` it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var form_elements = [{'name':'John'},{'age':'20'},{'gender':'Male'}];

var obj = {};

for (var i in form_elements) {
  obj[Object.keys(form_elements[i])[0]] = form_elements[i][Object.keys(form_elements[i])[0]]; 
}

console.log(obj); // {name: "John", age: "20", gender: "Male"}
```